# Error using string.h string object in C

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc

in cmd, I type: `gcc -v` to get the version of my compiler, this is what I get

> C:\Users\myStuff\Documents\C_Codes>gcc -v Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe Target: mingw32 Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure
>   --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=m ingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto
>   --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ ,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-l ibstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gm p-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld -- with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable- libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32
>   --with-libintl-prefix=/ mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T Thread model: win32 gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

I have looked in c:\minGW\include\ to try to find string.h and it is there but when I try to have I my C code something like:

string temp

I get the following compile error:

`error: unknown type name 'string'`

how can I fix this so I can use strings??

I have also included stdio.h, stdlib.h, and there are two string headers, string.h and strings.h

Comment: There is no `string` in C.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile the code using `g++`, because `c` language doesn't support a `string` type or else you can use character array for the same.

You can define character array and copy contents into array like this

```
char arr[SIZE];
strcpy(arr,"Your String");
```